# Elasticsearch mapping username incorrectly

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to create a visualize in Kibana dashboard.
Terms table that has a "-" in the field splits the item up
I have a "user" field in Kibana which is like

`p-john,`
`p-henry`

Whenever I query the user it splits the name and shows me the result like "p" as a separate user and john as a separate user. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: As this is string you can avoid this behaviour by indexing it as `not_analyzed` field. You can find more info here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2

Comment: That did not work, I have already tried it. The only thing we can do here is get the .raw field like user.raw field so that it wont split, I don't know how to get that .raw field in kabana.

Comment: @val Can you guys help me out?

Comment: As @avr explained, you need to modify your mapping to add that `not_analyzed` raw field. Please show your current mapping and how you're sending your data to ES.

Answer (score 0):

To get the raw field into Kibana click the configure button on the terms table, then click the "Panel" tab and by "Field" textbox enter "user.raw".